# probability of a die rolling 6, N times more often than any other number

Tags: probability, dice

I am looking for a way to calculate the possibility of a die rolling 6, at least N rolls more than any other number.

Here is an example:

Let's say I throw a die 100 times and I want to calculate the possibilty that the number 6 appears 20 rolls more than any other number.
So for example these could be the roll results:

6: 40x

5: 20x

4: 10x

3: 15x

2: 10x

1: 5x

So the 6 was rolled 20 rolls more than the 5.

Here is another example:

6: 50x

5: 10x

4: 30x

3: 10x

2: 0x

1: 0x

Here the 6 was rolled 20 rolls more than the 4. And so on. There must be an enormous number of cases in which this condition is satisfied.

I am looking for help on how to calculate the prbability, that the given condition is satisfied.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the total number of times you are rolling the die?

Comment: In the given example it is rolled 100 times.

Comment: Your phrase "$N$ times more often..." is ambiguous.  It can be read as "2 times more often..." or "10 times more often..." or...  Please write more carefully.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Getting the *exact* probability will be horrendously tedious.  One can approximate the probability of getting at least $N$ occurrences of $6$ more than any other however by asking the related question of a $6$ appearing at least $\frac{5N}{6}$ occurrences more than $\frac{R}{6}$ where $R$ is the number of rolls.  This can be done using a normal approximation to the binomial noting the average is $\frac{R}{6}$ and the standard deviation is $\sqrt{\frac{5R}{36}}$

Comment: For your given numbers of $N=20$ and $R=100$, this comes out to about $Pr(Z>2\sqrt{5})\approx 3.9\cdot 10^{-6}$, very unlikely.

Comment: there is no simple formula for this task, it is better to use a computer to evaluate these kind of probabilities